# Counting unique occurrences in each column

Tags: awk

I have a file with several columns like `$2$3` (until `$32`) as in

```
A refdevhet devdevhomo
B refdevhet refdevhet
C refrefhomo refdevhet
D devrefhet  refdevhet
```

I need to count how many occurrences of each unique element in each column separately

so that I have

```
refdevhet  2 3
refrefhomo 1 0
devrefhet  1 0
devdevhomo 0 1
```

I tried several variations of

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
  FS=OFS="\t"
}

{
  for(i=1; i<=32; i++) a[$i]++
}

END {
  for (i in a) print i, a[i]
}' file
```

but instead it's printing the cumulative sum of occurrences of unique elements across the selected fields.

Comment: Could you please post more clear samples on your question for better understanding of question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
    if (NF>mxf) mxf = NF;
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {ws[$i]=1; c[$i,i]++}
} 
END {
    for (w in ws) {
        printf "%s", w
        for (i=1;i<=mxf;i++) printf "%s%d", OFS, c[w,i];
        print ""
    }
}
```

Notice that solution is general. It will include first column into consideration as well. To omit the first column, change `i=1` to `i=2` in both places.

Comment: `ws[$i]=1` is not needed, `ws[$i]` is enough.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer! To do only for let's say $81-$91, do I change it to (i=81; i<=91; i++)  and (i=81;i<=91;i++) ? I gues I'm just confused about what  mxf is doing.

Comment: @MadzaFarias-Virgens, `mxf` is just remembering how many columns (or fields) were there in each row at most. If your input file has 91 columns, your way should work as well.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Andriy's good answer, with GNU awk you can use a 2-dimensional array

```sh
gawk '
  {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) count[$i][i]++}
  END {
    for (word in count) {
      printf "%s", word
      for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%d", OFS, count[word][i]
      print ""
    }
  }
' file | column -t
```

I'm assuming here that each line has the same number of fields as the last line.